# Create Sqlite DB before apk is created

Tags: sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I have a large DB*(~55MB)*. I can copy this database to the database path via asset.(in pieces).This process takes a lot of time after the application is installed on the phone.

Is there a solution that can do this before apk is created?

Thank You

Comment: Phone storage is slow; you'll never be able to move 55 MB of data fast.

Comment: Is there any other solution? CL., How can I do this. There are 600.000 row data. 
I have to register and process this datas.Which solution is effective.(XML,JSON, SQLite files.). I should be able to seaching in datas.Thanks.